# SharePoint 2010 Restrict List Types by Role

Tags: list, permissions, event-receivers, library

We have a requirement that members of a specific group should only be allowed to create discussion forums while administrators should be able to create any type of list/library.

Any advice on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Jason

Comment: I did not know how to do that or that it was some sort of requirement

Answer (score 1):

There is, to my knowledge, no built in way to do this. The best option would be to write an event receiver and look for the ListAdding event and cancel the operation if the person does not have the required role. Here is an article that might help you get started.

[Working with ListAdding and ListDeleting Events](http://www.sharepointbriefing.com/spcode/article.php/3851211/Working-with-ListAdding-and-ListDeleting-Events.htm)